# Collision, then what?

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, mathematics, terrain

I know how to check collision for example 2 `spheres`. But my question is how do I use the collsion response in a good way?

How do I make my character unable to walk in to the `Sphere`? I've got to the point where my game send a `PrintLn` when `isCollided` and it works but my character just walk through it.

How should I do?

Cheers!

Comment: The first intuitive options: _if objects moves and its position is inside the forbidden object, do not update the object's position_ or _if the object moves inside a restricted volume, project the object outside, onto the volume's surface (perhaps adding restitution force and switching velocity to point away from the object)_ . If these suffice, you may try either of them.. the last one can result in a lot of jitter for irregular volumes.

Comment: -1 as it doesn't appear that you even tried to research this.  Google will find you a ton of results on basic collision detection and resolution for game physics.  Also, the answers will depend a lot on information not provides, such as what behavior you want when the player collides with something (stop moving?  Slide?  Bounce?  Push the object?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best approach for this situation would be to use physics.

Take a look at this [2D collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional).

Basically, if you want a realistic collision, you have to give a concept of mass to your objects, and, after calculating that they collided, apply the respective equations.

If objects are not spheres, then the problem is way more complicated...

Comment: And there's already good physics engines around, e.g. [Box2D](http://box2d.org/).

Comment: Yes, the last resource (and also the most evolve one) would be a physics engine...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about your environment, i would say: simply put your character into a not moving (aka stopped) state. That can be achieved by setting his speed to 0 or may require more complex operations :D

Comment: there is one drawback to this approach though: say you have a sphere and point that falls under its own weight. if the point hits the sphere, then it will stick close to the sphere's surface. That can happen with a larger object: a car.. the natural behavior is to allow the object to slide against the sphere and continue falling. Your approach works for wolfenstein 3D like games (wall collisions) but you need the sliding effect even there. All in all, it's simple enough to proivde feedback.

Comment: Then how do you get out if your speed is 0 :P

Comment: If your speed is 0, that means you cannot move...

Comment: @AndroidXTr3meN you need a better approach then. Reflecting velocities, adding restitution forces, friction contact forces. Going for the best means writing a physics engine.

Comment: I've tried velocty.y and velocty.z *-1 but doesnt work.
And my game doesnt have to have best physics, collision like doom Elderscrolls Arena or Wolfenstein 3D is good enough

Comment: If you aim for general collision detection and want to spend some time, the topic is quite broad. Take a look at these books on the issue: [this](http://www.amazon.de/Collision-Interaction-Environments-Interactive-Technology/dp/155860801X/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1336999181&sr=8-5) and [this](http://www.amazon.de/Real-Time-Collision-Interactive-Technology-ebook/dp/B001086MGM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1336999181&sr=8-2)

Comment: Thanks! I know collsion is a HUGE part of game development. I have sphere and box collision

Comment: If you have some specific update equations, posting either a small snippet or explaining the approach might aid in finding out what the problem is with reflecting the velocity. Perhaps you're reflecting it each time you detect a collision? That results in the velocity oscillating (up-down) too fast - the object won't bounce off the surface/ground/sphere in that case.

Comment: My character have a Vector3 Position which are controlled by WASD Keys. the character also have a Sphere bounds that have same Position as the character.

Then I can use one of my methods to check if my character overlap with another object. But I have no idea what to write in the onOverlap == true

Comment: This isn't a even a proper question. Why not reading at least one of the tutorials you can easily find online? Sliding a body is equal to countering any perpendicular velocity related to the collided body. It's not even about programming, it's about physics.